# Why <from> tag disappear while trying to scrape from it? Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, scraper

I try to scrape some data from amazon and I need to sort the books by the number of reviews on this page:www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_283155_nr_n_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A!1000%2Cn%3A1&bbn=1000&ie=UTF8&qid=1457964444&rnid=1000
If I parse this page with scrapy framework, somehow the form tag disappears so I cant scrape it, why is that??

my browser sees it like this:
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sSrsK.jpg

scrapy framework sees it like this:
    [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vUz2P.jpg

this is what I see when I open the page with scrapy's open_in_browser() method

it's weird and I have no clue what's wrong
I appreciate your help

Comment: I don't know scrapy ... Could javascript running on the page change the results in the browser but not in scrapy?

Comment: The page perfectly runs without javascript I think it isnt my problem but thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried replicating your error and found that the scrapy shell redirects to another link when I opened the give url. When I viewed the response it was a completely different page than what is mentioned in the question with no `form` tag. 
This was the `Debug` code printed by scrapy :

```
2016-03-15 13:35:35 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.amazon.com/s?ie=UTF8&bbn=1000&page=1&rh=n%3A283155> from <GET http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_283155_nr_n_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A2Cn%3A1&bbn=1000&ie=UTF8&qid=1457964444&rnid=1000>
```

The solution to this is to try opening the url using a `user-agent`. Something like this:

```
scrapy shell -s USER_AGENT='Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7' "http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=lp_283155_nr_n_0?fst=as%3Aoff&rh=n%3A283155%2Cn%3A2Cn%3A1&bbn=1000&ie=UTF8&qid=1457964444&rnid=1000"
```

Comment: In the interests of completeness, can you explain how you found that scrapy shell does a redirect please?